# Django CMS Blog error 'No module named date_based'

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm using django CMS with the django cms blog plugin, but getting the following error:

```
ImportError at /en/
No module named date_based
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'cmsplugin_blog.middleware.MultilingualBlogEntriesMiddleware',
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

have tried importing the views:

```
from django.views.generic import *
```

and also tried extending the patterns from the view:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
```

Comment: FWIW, [there's a GitHub issue for a similar problem](https://github.com/fivethreeo/cmsplugin-blog/issues/88), which I found by Googling for 'No module named date_based'.

Comment: Yeah I saw this one, but not sure that can help me unless it's a version issue. here's my versions: python 2.7.1, django 1.5